# Custom BCS indexing connector: custom Managed Property is empty

Tags: powershell, search, 2016, managed-property, crawled-property

I've created a custom indexing connector for SharePoint 2016. The connector works but only the auto generated managed properties (grayed out) are filled.

If I create a new managed property and map it to one of the crawled properties, the managed property is always empty (retrievable, multiple crawls, after 24 hours).

It worked for SharePoint 2013.

How can I make it work for SharePoint 2016?

**Additional Information**:

1. **PropertySet**:

   The only working PropSet Guid is "bcc9619b-bfbd-4bd6-8e51-466f9241a27a". If I use another Guid (Script and INamingContainer) the search metadata category is always empty (no crawled properties). I don't know why!
2. **deployment**:

```
// copy connector to gac
// create RegEntry => protocol : OSearch16.ConnectorProtocolHandler.1
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity $SearchServiceAppName
New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlCustomConnector -SearchApplication $ssa -Protocol "myconn" -Name $searchconnectorname -ModelFilePath <Model Path>
get-service osearch16 | restart-service
New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory -Name "My Properties" -SearchApplication $ssa -PropSet "bcc9619b-bfbd-4bd6-8e51-466f9241a27a" -DiscoverNewProperties $true -AutoCreateNewManagedProperties $true
New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -Name "My Content" -SearchApplication $ssa -Type CustomRepository -CustomProtocol "myconn" -StartAddresses "myconn://"
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the PowerShell and just use the UI in the SSA to create the Managed Property from the BCS group of properties?